# Ajax on select control Jquery javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to do ajax when someone click on select control value. The problem is that onChange does not trigger ajax call jquery :(

This is what i have so far :)

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
 function swapContent(cv) {
    $("#myDiv").html('').show();
    var url = "ajax.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
       $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="dimenzije" onchange"javascript:swapContent(this);">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

My default content for this page element when the page initially loads

And AJAX.PHP

```
<?php 
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
echo $contentVar;
?>
```

Nothing triggers :(
But when i do something like this

```
     <a href="#" onClick="return false" onMouseDown="javascript:swapContent('Prva');">Content1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onMouseDown="javascript:swapContent('Druga');">Content2</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onMouseDown="javascript:swapContent('Treca');">Content3</a>
```

With A HREF all is working nice and smooth, where did I made mistake?

Comment: Use a proper event handler and it will most likely solve your issues.

Comment: Don't use inline scripts like: `<select name="dimenzije" onchange"javascript:swapContent(this);">`. Use `$('select').on('change', function (){...});`

Comment: Ok, can you please write a code, that i can try and accept answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the event handler [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // event handler
    $('select[name="dimenzije"]').on('change', function(event) {
        // get the value of the selection
        var cv = $(this).val(),
            url = "ajax.php";
        // change the hidden div's content to something if you're setting html().
        $("#myDiv").html('Loading...').show();
        // post
        $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
           // Replace with new content
           $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="dimenzije" id="swapContent">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code resides in 2 problems. Firstly the fact that you pass "this" as a parameter to contentSwap. And not an actual value.

Changing

```
{contentVar: cv}
```

to something like

```
{contentVar: $(cv).val()}
```

might work.

Secondly, you also have a typo in the html for the select element:

```
onchange"javascript:swapContent(this);"
```

Should be

```
onchange="javascript:swapContent(this);"
```

However like Alaa Badran mentioned this type of inline javascript is a no no.

Try something like this:

```
<select name="dimenzije">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('select[name="dimenzije"]').change(function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
            url = "ajax.php";

        $("#myDiv").html('').hide();

        $.post(url, {contentVar: $this.val()}, function(data) {
           $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also since you're using .show() before and after the ajax call, you can leave it out. Did you perhaps mean to call .hide() first then .show()?